# Can protection mode be turned off with inline assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, kernel, inline-assembly

If a user didn't have root privileges, could that user still write a user space program with inline assembly to turn off protection mode on the computer to overwrite memory in other segments assuming the OS is linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not unless the user knows of a security vulnerability to get root permissions. Mechanisms like /dev/mem allow root to read and write all userspace memory, and kernel module loading allows root access to kernel memory and the rest of the system's IO space.

Comment: My 5 cents - it should not necessarily be kernel vulnerability. There could be a vulnerable user-space process running with root privileges by exploiting which you could get a root, then load a kernel module that gets into protected mode.

Comment: True, and in fact he wouldn't need to load a kernel module to read/write all userspace memory, only to get to kernelspace. (edit: I wikied the answer, as it's now as much yours as mine :-)

Comment: I'm pretty fascinated by how the OS works to keep people from doing unauthorized things. Only from taking an introductory course in assembly it seemed to me that if you could just find a way to write to the code stack pointer then you've hijacked the system and you could pretty much do anything you want. Though if your only confined to your little segment then your still limited. Its just super interesting to me how one may get around that.

Comment: Indeed it is, very interesting. In brief, the OS manages all access to memory, so if you're running in userspace (anything outside the kernel) the kernel decides which memory you can access and which you can't. Not only does it protect each user's memory from other users, it protects each process's memory from other processes running as the same user. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the system is working as intended, no.

In reality, there are undoubtedly a few holes somewhere that would allow it -- given a code base that size, bugs are inevitable, and a few could probably be exploited to get into ring 0.

That said, I'm only guessing based on statistics -- I can't point to a specific vulnerability.